# What constitutes inaccurate in a credit report?

Tags: credit-report, dispute

What constitutes inaccurate in a credit report that can be disputed? I swear I have read everything I can online and its still confusing.

If the current amount owed has been lowered with payments and the credit report still reflects the original amount owed, is that inaccurate reporting that can be disputed?

Comment: Is it an adverse mark, late, defaulted etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have evidence that the information in the report is wrong then it is inaccurate.  Keep in mind that there is potentially a 30 day delay between when you pay and when the payment is reported to the credit bureau. [Experian example](https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/how-long-it-takes-for-0-balance-to-show-in-your-report/).

The credit bureaus claim that accuracy is based on what the reporting company tells them so if there's a problem, fixing it is going to involve them.

The FTC has an article on [disputing errors](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0151-disputing-errors-credit-reports)

Comment: would it make any difference if the information reporter is a government entity? Would an individual still have the same rights to dispute in accordance with that FTC article?

Comment: @daniel Yes. And with government agencies, sometimes you can call 3 times and get 3 different answers. It might benefit you to call them until you hear the right answer.